# kubernetes dashboard with a login screen

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

Hello everyone I was wondering what is the most secure way to deploy a kubernetes dashboard, through a nodePort, ngrok or a loadbalancer. The purpose of the dashboard should be on a kubernetes cluster on my raspberry pi cluster. The dashboard needs to be accessible to everyone on the network that's why I thought maybe nodePort is perfect. But I need some kind of a login screen where people could login instead of using the token to log in to the dashboard. For now, this is what I found about this that is a very simple tutorial to set up a dashboard through nodePort

https://www.thehumblelab.com/deploying-kubernetes-dashboard-in-the-lab/

Does anyone know a more secure way or how I need to deploy a login screen above this?

Answer (score 1):

My preference to expose cluster level UIs (dash, grafana, prometheus, kibana etc.) is to expose them over https with `Ingress` that supports basic auth. NginX ingress controller in my case, where adding basic auth is as simple as adding appropriate annotation.

Comment: I am a beginner in the whole kubernetes concept and found it very difficult to create an nginx ingress controller for my arm setup. I think i understand the way ingress works but somehow i can't get it up. especially cause i need a simple export in the my local network. so that people inside my network can access the dashboard. Can you direct me to good tutorials for setting up a ingress controller for the dashboard ?